# How to get variable's value out of a block?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I implemented a method as following:

```
-(void)startAnimating:(MyCompletion)performMethod {
_displayViewForActivityIndicator = [[ProcessingIndicationView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-self.view.frame.size.width, -self.view.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
[self.view addSubview:_displayViewForActivityIndicator];
LogDebug(@"Start the method");
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.5f
                      delay:0.0f
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                 animations:^{
                     //end position:
                     _displayViewForActivityIndicator.frame = self.view.frame;
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished)
 {
     performMethod();
 }];
```

}

I used this method as below:

```
  - (BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender: (id)sender
 {
 BOOL ret = NO;
 NSString *userId = [ViewsDataManager sharedManager].userID;
 LogDebug(@"userID = %@", userId);
 if ((userId!=nil)&&(![userId isEqualToString:@""])) {
    __block bool a = NO;
    [self startAnimating:^{
        a = [self deleteUserService];
        LogDebug(@"a1 = %d", a);
    }];
    LogDebug(@"a2 = %d", a);
    if (a) {
        [ViewsDataManager sharedManager].userID = nil;
        LogDebug(@"Delete user successfully");
        ret = YES;
    }
    else{
        ret = NO;
    }
}
LogDebug(@"ret == %d",ret);
return ret;
```

}

variable a is set in a block and I wanna use its value out of block. How can I do that?

Comment: Within the block, set `a` to where ever you want to use it.

Comment: block here is asynchronous; the rest of the code might finish before the block completes and value is assigned. Is there a reason why you can't work with the variable inside the block?

Comment: Declare a global variable and use that variable inside that block.

Comment: No, don't use a global variable.

Comment: I wanna get ret's value, it depends on a variable and if set ret = YES inside block and finally ret variable = NO. thanks @DavidJirman

Comment: I'm afraid this won't work the way you're picturing it ... the code outside lives its own live independently of the completion block (both live in parallel). If I were you I would try to restructure the code and push all `ret` value dependent code inside the block; another option would be to notify a delegate (or via notification) from within the block about the completion (you can also pass value around) and let the delegate perform some post-animation routines, but again this is a cannon for sparrows ...

Answer (score 4):

Your code doesn't make sense. The completion block will be called after the animation has run (async!), but you're accessing the variable before that. You might want to put that into the completion block as well.